# Is it possible to prevent a flex application from being resized at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, resize

From what I can gather, the resize property of a Flex application is set in the XML config file:

```
<!--Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true.-->
<!--<resizable></resizable>-->
```

However, if I set this attribute to true, is there a way to turn this off dynamically at runtime?  For example, my application has two view modes - mini and maxi.  I would like to prevent the end user from being able to resize the application when in mini mode.  I tried prevent the resize using the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
private function creationComplete():void {
    this.systemManager.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);
}

private function resizeListener(evt:Event):void {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This xml excerpt is from AIR application config. Are you using AIR?

Comment: Yeah, I'm creating an Adobe AIR application using Flex 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a new NativeWindow instance and reparent your application into that. When you create a new NativeWindow, you've got options you can set at Initialisation time, including resizable.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link.  This is probably what I was looking for.  Do you have some sample code I could use to move between mini mode and maxi mode (and vice versa) where mini is not resizeable and maxi is?

Comment: It's ok, I managed to sift through the documentation.  Thanks again for your post, it was very helpful.  For anyone who stumbles upon this, the NativeWindow documentation can be found here (there is a great example on how to create a new window just after the method descriptions): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to do that without setting the descriptor file property.

Here is the code:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" showGripper="false"
                    layout="vertical" showStatusBar="false"
                    applicationComplete="init()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexNativeWindowBoundsEvent;

        private function init():void
        {
            this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZING, onAppResize);
        }

        private function onAppResize(e:NativeWindowBoundsEvent):void
        {
                e.preventDefault();
        }

   ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html#resizable), `resizable` is read-only property.
So it's probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As this was already necro'd, and I was curious:

I was able to implement a switch from resizable to not with the following code:

```
private var maxMode:Boolean = true;

protected function switchMode():void
{
    if (maxMode){
        //I chose to freeze the app at current size
        //You could also set the min/max to hard coded values
        this.maxWidth = this.width;
        this.minWidth = this.width;
        this.maxHeight = this.height;
        this.minHeight = this.height;
    }
    else {
        //default values for WindowedApplication
        this.maxWidth = 2880;
        this.minWidth = 0;
        this.maxHeight = 2880;
        this.minHeight = 0;
    }

    maxMode= !maxMode
}
```

The user is however still shown the resize mouse icons on the edges of the app.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add return:

```
evt.preventDefault();
return;
```